# Flex to HTML : How to convert actionscript

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, apache-flex, converters

I'm converting a big application in Flash/Flex to HTML5/CSS/JS. I tried to translate AS classes but it's a bit difficult.
Do you know if I can find a JS equivalent to the natives AS classes?
Or if there is a reliable converter able to cross every classes of my app?

I can use ES6 format with the tags class, constructor, etc...

Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to find some information here, actually this is not ready-to-use  solution, but seems like someone tried to solve you problem: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/FlexJS

Comment: And https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/how-to/create-publish-html5-canvas-document.html

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna try it !